# Array foreach modification

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have an array `$testing` like this :

```
Array ( 
    [CUST_TYPE] => 
        Array ( 
            [0] => Family 
            [1] => Regular 
            [2] => Corporate 
            [3] => Premium ) 
    [TOTAL_BALANCE] => 
        Array ( 
            [0] => 420946131.01 
            [1] => 41272033223.93 
            [2] => 38873647942.4 
            [3] => 10465337565.61 ) 
        )
```

I need to convert (print) this array into something like this :

```
{
cust_type : Family,
balance : 420946131.01
},
{
cust_type : Regular ,
balance : 41272033223.93
},
and so on..
```

Here is simple foreach that I used, but it can only print `cust_type` or `balance`

```
$cols = array_keys($testing);

foreach ($testing[$cols[1]] as $i => $j) {
        echo '{cust_type : ' . $j . 
             ', balance : ' . $<What should I print??> . '},';        
    }
```

Kindly please to help.
Thank you.

Comment: Will the array always consist of only 2 sub-arrays?

Comment: @Andrew Yes, the array will always consist of only 2 sub arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [**array_map**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) (PHP 4 >= 4.0.6, PHP 5)

```
$json = json_encode(array_map(function($a,$b){ return array("cust_type"=>$a,"balance"=>$b);},$array["CUST_TYPE"],$array["TOTAL_BALANCE"]));
```

**Test**

```
[akshay@localhost tmp]$ cat test.php 
<?php

$array = array( 
            "CUST_TYPE" => array( 
                                'Family', 
                                'Regular', 
                                'Corporate', 
                                'Premium' 
                               ), 
            "TOTAL_BALANCE" => array( 
                                420946131.01, 
                                41272033223.93,
                                38873647942.4 ,
                                10465337565.61 
                              )
             );


// PHP 4,5
$json = json_encode(array_map(function($a,$b){ return array("cust_type"=>$a,"balance"=>$b);},$array["CUST_TYPE"],$array["TOTAL_BALANCE"]),JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

// Input
print_r($array);

// Output
print $json."\n";

?>
```

**Output**

```
[akshay@localhost tmp]$ php test.php 
Array
(
    [CUST_TYPE] => Array
        (
            [0] => Family
            [1] => Regular
            [2] => Corporate
            [3] => Premium
        )

    [TOTAL_BALANCE] => Array
        (
            [0] => 420946131.01
            [1] => 41272033223.93
            [2] => 38873647942.4
            [3] => 10465337565.61
        )

)
[
    {
        "cust_type": "Family",
        "balance": 420946131.01
    },
    {
        "cust_type": "Regular",
        "balance": 41272033223.93
    },
    {
        "cust_type": "Corporate",
        "balance": 38873647942.4
    },
    {
        "cust_type": "Premium",
        "balance": 10465337565.61
    }
]
```

Comment: nicely done, i was trying to figure out using `array_map()`, but couldn't achieve.

Answer (score 3):

Consider this snippet,

```
for($i=0; $i<count($your_array['CUST_TYPE']); $i++)
{
    $required[] = [ 'cust_type' => $your_array['CUST_TYPE'][$i],
                    'balance' => $your_array['TOTAL_BALANCE'][$i] ];
}

$required = json_encode($required);
```

will output,

```
[{"cust_type":"Family","balance":420946131.01},{"cust_type":"Regular","balance":41272033223.93},{"cust_type":"Corporate","balance":38873647942.4},{"cust_type":"Premium","balance":10465337565.61}]
```

---

For other format, You can use [`array_combine()`](http://php.net/array_combine) creates an array with first argument as keys and second as values,

The format you are specifying is `json` So, `json_encode()` will do that for you,

```
$required = array_combine($your_array['CUST_TYPE'], $your_array['TOTAL_BALANCE']); 

$required = json_encode($required);
```

Now, `$required` is string with your desired value. Which is,

```
{"Family":420946131.01,"Regular":41272033223.93,"Corporate":38873647942.4,"Premium":10465337565.61}
```

Note: Make sure you have same number of members in both `$your_array['CUST_TYPE']` and `$your_array['TOTAL_BALANCE']` arrays inside your input array. Otherwise you will see a warning.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer.. But I need to add identifier for each data. E.g : {cust_type : family, balance : 1234},{cust_type : corporate, balance : 12345}, so on.. The json_encode will only produce {"Family":"420946131.01","Corporate":"41272033223.93"}. Hence I think we need to put loop there.